# How to replace a path(c:\test\sqr.ini) in a .ini file using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to replace a line in a .ini file.

Currently my script looks like this...

```
clear

    $file= "D:\sqr.ini"
     $path="c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC;" 
     $newpath="c:\myprod\sqlrs\test;" 
    get-content $file |
     Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $path,$newpath } | Set-Content D:\result.ini
```

But this is giving me an error of

```
Invalid regular expression pattern: c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC;.
At line:7 char:38
+          Foreach-Object { $_ -replace <<<<  $path,$newpath } | Set-Content D:\result.ini
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC;:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression

Invalid regular expression pattern: c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC;.
At line:7 char:38
+          Foreach-Object { $_ -replace <<<<  $path,$newpath } | Set-Content D:\result.ini
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC;:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Could you offer some advice please as to why this isn't working, any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the .ini file

```
[INFO] PROVIDER=; 

OUTPUT=c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC.ini;
TABLENAME=; 

OUTPUT=c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC.ini;
DEFAULTQUERY=;
VERSION=1,50,3518,0;
TABLE=Privlib;

OUTPUT=c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC.ini;
PROVIDER=TestPWProv_VC;
TABLENAME=Privlib;
```

Comment: You should provide an example of your ini file and code what you have tried so far.

Comment: [INFO] PROVIDER=; 

OUTPUT=c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC.ini;
TABLENAME=; 

OUTPUT=c:\bin\TestPWProv_VC.ini;
DEFAULTQUERY=;
VERSION=1,50,3518,0;
TABLE=Privlib;


I need to change the path in this file (its just an example not the real one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Future please try researching before just simply asking a question, i'm sure others won't be as straightforward in the future.

```
$file= "D:\sqr.ini"
$newpath="c:\myprod\sqlrs\test;"
(Get-Content $path) -replace 'OUTPUT=.+', ("OUTPUT=$newpath") | Set-Content $path
```

Comment: Thanks Dewi I will try this , thanks for the help greatly appreciated !!

Comment: I replaced the PATH AND NEWPATH with my requirements but not working

Comment: could you please update your question to include the lines srom the ini file and the code you currently have

Comment: I have included the .ini file I need that output path to be replaced with a custom one..please help

Comment: Check my answer for edits, literally run just that script and that will do what you want